# .htaccess redirect issue

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I am stuck in this .htaccess issue and not able to get a solution. Tried everything but as I am new to htaccess may be the codes are just not matching and it gives me a error.

There is a php file I am working..

This is the result I get now

http://website.com/page.php?url=diploma-in-film-acting

Now I want this to work like this

http://website.com/diploma-in-film-acting

or may be this

http://website.com/diploma-in-film-acting.html

How do I get this to work ???

I have already used this code

I already did this but I get a 404 error when I add this to the url http://website.com/diploma-in-film-acting.html

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ page.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ page.php?url=$1
```

Thanks

Comment: use apache `mod_rewrite`

Comment: thanks @mithunsatheesh ... I got that I need to use this mod_rewrite but what do I add to the htaccess to make it look like that ?

Comment: if u r testing this on localhost the you need to use rewritebase for the proper redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now :-

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ page.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ page.php?url=$1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /page.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I already did this but I get a 404 error when I add this to the url http://website.com/diploma-in-film-acting.html

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ page.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ page.php?url=$1

Comment: you have to add rule in .htaccess file then open this url :- website.com/diploma-in-film-acting.html

Comment: add... Options +FollowSymLinks.. at the start

Answer (score 1):

Use `mod_rewrite` of Apache! And in your `.htaccess`, give this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /page.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

For the directory based rewriting, use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /page.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.phpurl$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Optionally, if you have any query strings, that will be passed via `&%{QUERY_STRING}`.

Comment: I already did this but I get a 404 error when I add this to the url http://website.com/diploma-in-film-acting.html

'code'
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ page.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ page.php?url=$1

Comment: Nopes, try the one from here and say. :) Copy the full one and try both the URLs.